# Create a list with text, image, button in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I would like to have a view on my `storyboard`, with a part of text, then an image, then another part of text and finally a `button`. Text and image has to be variable and could be changed. Most of the time, text will be very long.

I m looking for the best way to perform it.

Should i use a `UIScrollView` and input a label, an image, a label and a button ?

Or just a label, an image, a label and a button ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to just a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`. For the `UILabel` you can add an attributed string. Attributed strings can also contain images, so you can have the image inline with the text. Your code will be something like this:

```
var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "myImageName")
let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
var myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text before image")
myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
myString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "Text after image"))
myLabel.attributedText = myString
```

And after this you can add your `UIButton`.

As for the text being too long, you should rather make the `UILabel` multi-line. Horizontally scrollable text doesn't provide the best user experience.

Comment: thx, i will check this afternoon and i revert to u, but seems an appropriate way.

Comment: just checked, and when i try this, i ve got : in the label : Text before imageText after image. When i replace myImageName by paris.jpg for example, nothing appears... Have you an idea ?

Comment: it's working with UIText not with UILabel, could you confirm ?